# copying array onto range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the values of the array `mastersheet()` onto a range of cells of equal size.

`mastersheet()` is initially declared as a variant
`Dim mastersheet() As Variant`

Eventually in the code it has 4 "columns" or dimensions.
`ReDim mastersheet(1, 1, 1, 1)`

Eventually strings are added to it in column 2, or the second dimension. Not all column have the same data type.

`wbmastersheet.Worksheets(1).range("A1:D" & UBound(mastersheet, 4)) = mastersheet()`

I am getting the below error

> Error 13: type mismatch

Can anyone please resolve this ?

Comment: Also worth noting that `range("A1:D" & UBound(mastersheet, 4))` would return an error as `UBound()` returns an integer.  `Range()` requires a string, therefore you would have to convert the integer to a string `range("A1:D" & CStr(UBound(mastersheet, 4)))`

Comment: This was likely the cause of your error 13 as you were trying to concatenate a string with an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the **rank** with the actual dimension.

Rewrite your code so that **mastersheet** is 1 to *x*, 1 to 4. Put the values into the array as,

```
redim mastersheet(1 to 2, 1 to 4)
mastersheet(1, 1) = "A1"
mastersheet(1, 2) = "B1"
mastersheet(1, 3) = "C1"
mastersheet(1, 4) = "D1"
mastersheet(2, 1) = "A2"
mastersheet(2, 2) = "B2"
mastersheet(2, 3) = "C2"
mastersheet(2, 4) = "D2"
```

Write the values back to the worksheet like this,

```
wbmastersheet.Worksheets(1).range("A1").Resize(UBound(mastersheet, 1), UBound(mastersheet, 2)) = mastersheet
```

Comment: But mastersheet() at this point is the result of a code which added vales to it... the only way to know the dimensions of the array is to use the UBound function, as far as i know.

Comment: If you have an array of values that imitates the rows × columns on a worksheet then you have a 1 to *x*, 1 to *y* array. *x* is the number of rows nad *y* is the number of columns. If you have two 'records' of 4 fields (e.g. A1:D2) then you have 1 to 2, 1 to 4. **Not** (1, 1, 1, 1).

Comment: you are right, this was a very big conceptual mistake on my part.

Comment: No worries; I hope the above simple demo helps sort things out.